# File last modifed Comperator

Tags: java, compare

I implemented comparator to sort file array by last modified, from new to old.

Since lastModifed returns long rather than int, and the `compare` method returns int, and I assumed that the `compare` method should return a positive int when arg0 is "bigger" then arg1, and non-positive int when not,I wrote:

```
private class FileModComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    @Override
    public int compare (File file1, File file2) {
       if (file1.lastModified() - file2.lastModified() > 0) {
            return 0;
        } 
        else {
            return 1;
        }
}
```

Then I called:

```
Arrays.sort(fileArray, fileModComparator);
```

No sort applied upon the array (the array was sorted, by chance, from old to new).

I changed FileModComparator to:

```
private class FileModComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare (File file1, File file2) {
        return (int)(file1.lastModified() - file2.lastModified())*-1;
        }
}
```

That worked fine, with the risk of getting long instead of int.

1) Why the first version of my comparator didn't work?

2) How can I avoid the long result risk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `else` statement you consider the element as superior if it is equal or inferior and you consider it as equal as it is superior :

```
if (file1.lastModified() - file2.lastModified() > 0) {
    return 0;
 } 
 else {
    return 1;
 }
```

It appears wrong. 
You should handle each case distinctly and consistently and also use `Long.compare()` that will reduce your code to :

```
return Long.compare(file1.lastModified(), file2.lastModified() );
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Java-8 and above you can just use this comparator, instead of creating your own class for that:

```
Comparator<File> comparator = Comparator.comparingLong(File::getLastModified);
```

Which is equal to something like this:

```
Comparator<File> comparator = 
    (left, right) -> Long.compare(left.getLastModifed(), right.getLastModified());
```

Comment: Short one-liner that doesn't have complicated stuff like math. And you don't even need to create a class!

Comment: @Jai that's what I like about Java-8 and above. Common code which is used everywhere is just replaced with a method call. The developer doesn't really need to know anymore how the comparison works, as long as it is readable.

Comment: @Lino No JAVA 8 here.. and I was reffering your pre-edit post

Comment: @Alaychem Java-11 is coming out and you're still using something below Java-8? That means it's really time for an upgrade.

Comment: @Lino I upvoted your answer, its "cooler", but I'll use david's.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version never returns a negative number, so you've implemented only 2/3 of what `compare()` should do.

The numbers themselves don't matter, so `-1`, `0` and `1` can and often are used as return values.

Comment: can you give a source?

Comment: @Alaychem For what? That the numbers don't matter? Haven't you even read the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) before you start writing code? You should be ashamed of yourself, asking me for "source" when it reads right in the damn Javadocs.

Comment: @Alaychem The only thing you need to be concerned is that if `compare(x, y)` gives a positive number, then `compare(y, x)` must give a negative number, and vice versa. The loss of precision has no effect, so there is no risk.

Comment: @Jai that's just one of the requirements. It also needs to be transitive. But these are for writing comparators by hand. There are so many easier ways (as shown in other answers, e.g. `comparingLong`) in modern Java.

Comment: @Kayaman Actually, I went to javadocs, but somehow I missed that. oops. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use compare from `Long` something like that:

```
private class FileModComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    @Override
    public int compare (File file1, File file2) {
        return Long.compare(file1.lastModified(), file2.lastModified());
    }
}
```